# YouTube artist charts api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Does YouTube expose it's artist charts via api or is there a way to get the charts data using the youtube api?

I'm talking about the charts data here https://artists.youtube.com/charts/videos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible using the official Youtube API, if we look at https://artists.youtube.com/charts/videos, it uses YouTube Internal API (InnerTube) with a specific API key (registered to use `youtubei` API which is not available to developers)

Of course it's a hack just FYI

The API key has `https://artists.youtube.com` configured as referer, adding the custom header: `x-referer:https://artists.youtube.com` make it works :

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -H "x-referer:https://artists.youtube.com" \
     "https://content.googleapis.com/youtubei/v1/browse?alt=json&key=AIzaSyCzEW7JUJdSql0-2V4tHUb6laYm4iAE_dM" \
     -d '{
     "context": {
          "client": {
               "clientName": "WEB_MUSIC_ANALYTICS",
               "clientVersion": "0.2",
               "theme": "MUSIC",
               "hl": "en",
               "gl": "FR",
               "experimentIds": []
          },
          "capabilities": {
          },
          "request": {
               "internalExperimentFlags": []
          }
     },
     "browseId": "FEmusic_analytics",
     "query": "chart_params_type=WEEK&perspective=CHART&flags=viral_video_chart&selected_chart=VIRAL_VIDEOS"
    }'
```

If it doesn't work, get the API key from the network log of https://artists.youtube.com

In the `query` field, you can modify the `selected_chart` parameter :

- all video :

  ```
  selected_chart=VIDEOS
  ```
- viral videos chart :

  ```
  selected_chart=VIRAL_VIDEOS
  ```
- artists :

  ```
  selected_chart=ARTISTS
  ```
- tracks :

  ```
  selected_chart=TRACKS
  ```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful

Comment: it is not working for me. is it still working?